# Deciphering a word from a Spanish birth record (1903 Latin America)

Tags: birth-records, palaeography, 1900s-decade, nicaragua

I got my hands on a 1903 birth certificate from Managua, Nicaragua. I speak Spanish (as a non-native), but have issues to decipher one word shown below. I can read ... de Granada.

[image]

The whole record for context can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cco305v5xrdfpb1/Balladares_Josefa_Dolores_Birth_1903.jpg?dl=0), see the (second) column for Josefa Dolores Balladares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the word is [***oriunda***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oriundo#Spanish), meaning **native** to Granada. The dot on the *i* has strayed forward a little and the minims are difficult to differentiate. The word also appears in the entry above and is somewhat more clear there.